# If I want to write PERIOD, is it after dot? Is dot even required?

Tags: punctuation, writing

We all know that the **word** 'PERIOD' is used to convey your stance firmly. Period **means** 'full stop', **that's it!**

> **Spoken Sentence** - *"You are not doing that [a little pause] PERIOD"*

But what if I want to write it? Do we require a full stop. If yes, where the *word* 'PERIOD' goes? Also, do we have comma? semi colon?  Which one is preferred out of these:

**Written Sentences**

> You are not doing that. Period. *(two 'full stops')* **or** 
>  You are not doing that, period. *(first comma, in last full stop)* **or** 
>  You are not doing that, period *(only comma, no full stop)* **or** 
>  You are not doing that period *(no comma or full stop)* **or** 
>  You are not doing that; period. *(semi colon and in last, full stop)*

Comment: [Related question on ELU.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76956/punctuation-of-sentence-ending-with-the-word-period-for-emphasis)

Comment: @J.R. oh...it did not show up in Google results! so..it's comma and period period! thanks :)

Comment: It's hard to find that question on ELU because so many questions ask about the period (the punctuation mark) as opposed to "Period!" (the emphatic exclamation). I only found it because I knew it was there – and even then, I almost gave up :^)

Comment: It's American English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You are not doing that. Period. (two 'full stops')

OK. "Period." is an exclamation. You could also use an "!".

> You are not doing that, period. (first comma, in last full stop)

OK

---

> You are not doing that, period (only comma, no full stop)

No. Sentences need a period at the end regardless of what is written.

> You are not doing that period (no comma or full stop)

No. Sentences need a period at the end regardless of what is written.

> You are not doing that; period. (semi colon and in last, full stop)

No. Semi-colon is not appropriate since it is not separating independent clauses.

Comment: For the exclamation, you could also employ a dash: _"You are not doing that – period!"_